# System.AccessViolationException when loading C++ in vb.net application

Tags: c++, vb.net

I am working on a .net application. I found an example for an API call that is written in CPP and I am having issues translating it to VB.net.

The C++ example

```
    void InvokeClientMethord()
    {
      HINSTANCE adapter_dll_handle = loadLibraryA("dllName.dll");

     if(adapter_dll_handle != Null)
     {
       const char* functionName = "CommandName";
       typedef xanydictionary_ptr (WINAPIV *FARPROC)(xrstring, xanydictionary_ptr);
       FARPROC ExecuteWgmCustomCmd = (FARPROC)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)adapter_dll_handle,functionName);
       if (ExecuteWgmCustomCmd != NUL)
       {
        xrstring cust_id = "ThisIsSomeName";
        xanydictionary_ptr pInputParms, pResponseParms;
        pInputParms = xanydictionary::create ();
        pInputParms -> set (xstring ("testMessage"), "This is test message.");
        pResponseParms = ExecuteWgmCustomCmd(cust_id, pInputParms);
        if (pResponseParms.isnull ())
               return ;
       }
      }
    }
```

In the above example,xanydictionary_ptr, xrstring are type definitions inside the c++ lib

typedef const char *xrstring;
typedef xrchandle xanydictionary_ptr;

in the above type definitions, xrchandle is a class specific to the API and xanydictionary is also specific to the api. it a dictionary specified in the xrchandle class.

My VB Translation

```
   Public Class SomeClass
    <DllImport("dllName.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, PreserveSig:=False, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint:="executeCustomCommand")>
    Public Shared Function executeCustomCommand(cust_id As IntPtr, params As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Private Structure xanydictionary_ptr
      Public VarName As IntPtr
      Public varValue As IntPtr
    End Structure

    Public sub InvokeClientMethord()
      Dim cust_id As String = "ThisIsSomeName"
      Dim cust_id_ptr As IntPtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(cust_id)
      Dim pInputParms As New xanydictionary_ptr With {
        .VarName = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("testMessage"),
        .varValue = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni("This is test message."))
      }
      Dim pInputParms_ptr As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(pInputParms))
      Marshal.StructureToPtr(inputStrct, pInputParms_ptr, True)
      Dim pResponseParms As IntPtr = executeCustomCommand(CustPrt, StructPtr)
    End Sub
   End Class
```

When my subroutine is called it throws a System.AccessViolationException 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. this is often an indication that another memory is corrupt'.

Comment: What line does that error occur on?

Comment: @Nanhydrin  
at "Dim pResponseParms As IntPtr = executeCustomCommand(CustPrt, StructPtr)"

Comment: please provide a [mre], what is a `xrstring`, `xanydictionary_ptr`, what does `xanydictionary::create` do?

Comment: @AlanBirtles

those are typedef inside the C++ API. 
typedef xrchandle<xanydictionary>     xanydictionary_ptr;
typedef const char          *xrstring

Comment: Edit your question to include those details, the next question would be what is `xrchandle` and `xanydictionary`